# Transient variables are not captured properly on form submission

Tags: java, seam, richfaces

My User entity class have several member variables (e.g. String firstName) which are persisted and some transient variables (e.g. transient boolean selected) which are not.

I have used the transient variable to capture a checkbox selection, but invariably the value never gets set and procesed properly until I set another bean value along with it.

i.e. If User has firstName (mapped to a text field) and selected (mapped to a checkbox)
If I just selected the value doesn't seem to be set on an update
If I had selected the checkbox and the firstName field, the "selected" value is captured properly

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
@Entity @Table(name = "User") 
public class User implements Serializable { 

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY) 
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) 
    private Integer id; 

    @Column(name = "first_Name") 
    private String firstName; 

    @Transient private boolean selected; // getters and setters 
} 

            <rich:dataTable value="#{users}" var="_user" style="width:auto;">
...
                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Select</f:facet>
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{_user.selected}"/>
                </rich:column>
            </rich:dataTable>
```

Comment: wow, that was all one sentence. Sorry, I didn't understand a thing. Perhaps show code?

Comment: @Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "first_Name")
    private String firstName;

    @Transient
    private boolean selected;

    // getters and setters  
}

<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userHome.instance.selected}"/>

Comment: add the code to your question (edit). It is almost unreadable this way.

Comment: And this isn't enough. The provided code doesn't give enough information about your problem.

Comment: I've no answer just a hint, values from checkboxes are only transfered it checked.

Comment: @Kalpana - add a `<h:messages />` tag to your view to see if validation/etc. is preventing the _update model values_ phase from executing.

Comment: I don't see any validation specific warnings or errors though

Comment: Can you show your code that is submitting the values? (ie. where is the commandButton).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just saw a workaround to this issue. We were able to capture the value of the selected variable in our action classes (e.g. EntityQuery) but it didn't work in the @PreUpdate methods exposed by the entity. This seems to work fine now.